# The chat help-text for guests is unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat, user-interface

I hopped on chat for the Town Hall and saw this at the bottom of the window:

[image: help text]

The logo doesn't look great, but the real problem is that the help text is completely unreadable. Highlighting it gives:

> You must be logged in to talk. See the faq for more information.

I'm tagging this [bug](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) instead of [feature-request](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), but if someone better suited disagrees feel free to re-tag.

Comment: Nope, that thar be a layout bug. Good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm tagging this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) instead of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but if someone better suited disagrees feel free to re-tag.

Sometimes there's disagreement about the distinction between those two, but readable text is a feature that can be expected by default, so [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is just fine in this case :)

Fixed now, thanks.